# I want to use a function of Objective-C in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to get the width of a String, and I get the answer which is use this method( but it is just in OC): [image]

I find it in Official API Document. Of course there is no Swift version.
Due to I know nothing about OC, I can't write all my code with OC language. But I find out that I can create a `XXX-Bridging-Header.h` file, and import the header files of OC that I want to use in `.swift` File.

However I don't know which header file is this function in. I hope someone could tell me the file name OR point out another way to get the width of String.

Fairly Appreciate!!

Comment: What is OC? It looks like Objective-C to me. Never heard of OC in my life.

Comment: @gnasher729 OC just means Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the api [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:) and you will find: NSString.

As you can see it's in NSString so you don't need to add it to the bridging header. Swift does toll-free bridging between swift strings and NSString however, this method is deprecated so you might have to use a NSString explicitly (not recommended)

Comment: Thank you @barksten ! I think this is the exact reason why there is no code hints pop out when I input "size...."! :D Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` method was deprecated in iOS 7.0.

The replacement is `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` and is available from Swift.

Here is a usage example:

```
let myString = "Hello World" as NSString
let width = 100.0 as CGFloat
let height = 40.0 as CGFloat
let maxSize = CGSizeMake(width, height)
let options: NSStringDrawingOptions  = [.TruncatesLastVisibleLine, .UsesLineFragmentOrigin]
let attr = [ NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17) ]
let labelBounds = myString.boundingRectWithSize(maxSize, options: options, attributes: attr, context: nil)
```

The result is in `labelBounds` as a `CGRect`. For this example, it is

```
{x 0 y 0 w 88.312 h 20.287}
```

Comment: Thank you ,man! That's so detail ! Thank you for helping me know more about the parameters!

Comment: No problem, @Microos. I hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The function you want deprecated and it Replace by:

```
CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FONT}
                             context:nil];
```

You can set size:

```
CGSize size = textRect.size;
```

In Swift:

```
 NSString(string).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width, DBL_MAX),
                                      options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                      attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: FONT],
                                      context: nil)
```

FONT is the font you want.